# Use VBA to determine if a table can be edited

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have the following procedure in Form_Load:

```
Dim accObject As Access.AccessObject

For Each accObject In CurrentData.AllTables
    Me.cboSelectTable.AddItem accObject.Name
Next
```

This populates the combo box with ALL the tables including system tables and those linked to SQL Server. The problem is, I am only hoping to get back tables which can be edited. How can this be determined using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When retrieving your set of target table names you can ignore system tables (`Like "MSys*"`) and temporary tables (`Like "~*"`).  And ignore linked tables by checking whether the `Connect` property is anything other than a zero-length string.

```vb
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    With tdf
        If Not (.Name Like "~*" Or .Name Like "MSys*") Then
            If Len(.Connect) = 0 Then
                Me.cboSelectTable.AddItem .Name
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next
Set tdf = Nothing
```

If that doesn't give you everything you want, you can also check whether `tdf.Updatable` is True for each table.